# How to query gatsby image using graphiql

Tags: graphql, gatsby

i have image in `/src/assests/images/basketball` which I want to query using graphiql.

I tried pasting this in my graphiql

```
query {
  placeholderImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "basketball.jpeg" }) {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it keeps on saying `...GatsbyImageSharpFluid` unknown fragment. I have a vague idea about graphQL but can someone help me out on how i can query queries using graphiQl in gatsby?

This is my gatsby.config.js

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assests/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        // icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
```

And my folder structure of where the files are

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Gatsby image fragments limitation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#fragments)

> Note, due to a limitation of GraphiQL, you can not currently use these fragments in the GraphiQL IDE.

In GraphiQL change your query to:

```
query {
  placeholderImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "basketball.jpeg" }) {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
        base64
        aspectRatio
        src
        srcSet
        sizes
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is giving data as `null` to be more precise `{
  "data": {
    "file": null
  }
}`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.